# Getting parents subvalue from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this kind of a xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<setting>
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
  <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
  <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 1" />
  <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
  <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
 <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
    <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name1" />
 </Key>
 <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
    <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name2" />
 </Key>
</Key>
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
  <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
  <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 2" />
  <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
  <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
    <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name3" />
</Key>
<Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
    <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
    <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name4" />
  </Key>
 </Key>
</setting>
```

And i would like do get rsv-group-name data="value" from the rsv-login-name data="value"

that is i give the parser name3 and i want it to return group 2

as best i have come up until now is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="umm" match="Value" use="@data"/>
<xsl:key name="amm" match="Value" use="@name"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="key('umm','name3')">
 <p>    
<xsl:value-of select="../../@name" />
 </p> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Witch gives me "com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" not exactly the best result :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../Value[@name = 'rsv-group-name']/@data"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**A solution using keys for efficiency:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValueByData" match="Value" use="@data"/>

 <xsl:key name="kValueByKeyAndName" match="Value"
  use="concat(generate-id(..), '+', @name)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "key('kValueByKeyAndName',
          concat(generate-id(key('kValueByData', 'name3')/../..),
                       '+',
                       'rsv-group-name'
                 )
          )
           /@data
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<setting>
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
        <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 1" />
        <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
        <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
        <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
            <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
            <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name1" />
        </Key>
        <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
            <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
            <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name2" />
        </Key>
    </Key>
    <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.UserGroup" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
        <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="1328200856753" />
        <Value name="rsv-group-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="group 2" />
        <Value name="rsv-user-type" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="backup-user" />
        <Value name="rsv-owner" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="" />
        <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
            <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
            <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name3" />
        </Key>
        <Key name="com.ahsay.afc.cpf.User" content="" allowMultiple="Y">
            <Value name="rsv-id" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="13279083887401" />
            <Value name="rsv-login-name" inheritParentAttribute="Y" type="string" data="name4" />
        </Key>
    </Key>
</setting>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
group 2
```